# How To Find Out What A User "Liked" Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently calling the facebook **me/home** edge to get the users home feed. In the results I might get an entry like the JSON posted below.

My question is, when I get an entry like that where the user's friend **".. likes a link."** How do I find out what link they liked? I'm trying to get the title and URL, but can't seem to figure out how. I've try just about every option using facebook's graph explorer.

Ideally, I would like that information to be returned when I made the **/me/home** request. I tried adding "attachments" to the fields parameter, but that didn't work.

```
  {
      actions=({
        link="https://www.facebook.com/10154950234790111/posts/323892414481111";name=Comment;
      });
      comments={

      };
      "created_time"="2015-01-02T23:18:16+0000";from={
        id=10154950234790453;name="Brian Joe";
      };
      id="10154950234790453_3238924144862222";
      likes={

      };
      privacy={
        value="";
      };
      story="Brian Joe likes a link.";
"story_tags"={
        0=({
          id=10154950234790111;
          length=14;
          name="Brian Joe";
          offset=0;
          type=user;
        });
      };
      type=status;
      "updated_time"="2015-01-02T23:18:16+0000";
    }
```

Comment: You are aware that /me/home requires read_stream permission that you will not be approved for?

Comment: @WizKid Yes, I have that permission granted.

Comment: That was not what I said. You will need to get the permission approved by Facebook otherwise it will stop working at 4/30/2015. You can read more about the requirements to get approved at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

Answer (score 1):

This is a long standing bug in Facebook, probably older than two years.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/648986871793611/
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/522743067756848/

I and many others have given up trying to repro this for Facebook Support.

You can give it a go if you want by reporting it to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Ideally Facebook should be inserting the object target in the `story_tags` like this

```
 {
      "story": "phwd likes Moët & Chandon.", 
      "story_tags": {
        "0": [
          {
            "id": "13608786", 
            "name": "phwd", 
            "offset": 0, 
            "length": 17, 
            "type": "user"
          }
        ], 
        "24": [
          {
            "id": "38995979792", 
            "name": "Moët & Chandon", 
            "offset": 24, 
            "length": 14, 
            "type": "page"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "id": "13608786_10101895322580287", 
      "created_time": "2015-01-03T17:35:51+0000"
    },
```

Where this object

```
"24": [
              {
                "id": "38995979792", 
                "name": "Moët & Chandon", 
                "offset": 24, 
                "length": 14, 
                "type": "page"
              }
            ]
```

Would instead be something like

```
"24": [
              {
                "id": "event_id", 
                "name": "Name of event", 
                "offset": 24, 
                "length": 14, 
                "type": "event"
              }
            ]
```

So it ends up really being a feature request.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I reported a bug, and got a response saying they "won't fix" it.